# Signed URLs for Magic Links (passwordless login)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I was wondering if I could use Signed URLs for Magic Link login (passwordless). I know people are using tokens that are stored in the database and later on compare to whom each token belongs to and if is still valid.

```
    /**
     * Get the verification URL for the given notifiable.
     *
     * @param  \App\User  $user
     * @return string
     */
    protected function authenticationUrl(User $user): string
    {
        return URL::temporarySignedRoute(
            'login.magic_link.authenticate',
            now()->addMinutes(10),
            ['uuid' => $user->uuid]
        );
    }
```

I am sending the link to my app using the Signed URLs provided with Laravel. And if the user clicks on the link he is redirected to the authenticate method.

```
    /**
     * Authenticate validated user.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\View\View
     * @throws \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException
     */
    public function authenticate(Request $request): RedirectResponse
    {
        try {
            $user = User::where($request->only('uuid'))->firstOrFail();
        } catch (ModelNotFoundException $e) {
            return redirect()->route('login.magic_link.index')
                ->withErrors(['email' => 'Email address could not be found.']);
        }

        Auth::login($user);
        return redirect()->route($this->redirectTo);
    }
```

The question is if this is safe and considered as a good practice. And if bad, can someone explain to me why?

Comment: This is called security by obscurity. You have a url that is publicly accessible, but it's hard to guess. You can look up the pros and cons of this approach in many places. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity

Comment: Also, I don't see where you are validating the URL signature. Without that, signed routes are useless.

Comment: yeah definitely throw the `$request->hasValidSignature()` call in there somewhere to verify the signature as @newUserName02 said

Comment: the signature validating middleware is in the route file, my question is why is this security by obscurity? The link is well known but you have to the token that guarantees that only you can access this link in a specific period of time: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/urls#signed-urls

Comment: Because the token does not guarantee that only you can access the link,  anyone with the full link (with token) can access it,  it is unlikely, because the full link is very long and well,  obscure.